# Can I use YUI compressed when building ASP.NET projects in VS2010

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, yui, minify

I want to minify java script files in my vs2010 web app ASP.NET solution. I know that YUI compressor can do it pretty well on its own. So I was wondering if I can do the following:

1. I have all JS files in the Scripts folder in my solution.
2. JS files are included into aspx pages as follows:

`<script src="Scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

1. It would be nice to minify the 'scripts.js' file when building "Release" configuration, as well as when I'm publishing my web app.

Can someone explain here how to automate it all in VS2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft actually has a pretty good solution for this. You can read about it [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/10/16/using-the-new-microsoft-ajax-minifier.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It pretty much does it, but honestly why don't they just build it into Visual Studio? Doesn't it sound as an obvious thing. Anyway, at the current stage of things that Ajax Minifier is so complicated that I think I'll go with just manually calling YUI compressor from a batch file after the build is done.

Answer (score 0):

competent_tech's answer would achieve your objective by using the Microsoft Ajax Minifier in an MSBuild Task. The Ajax Minifier is another minification tool that essentially does the same thing that the YUI compressor does. Its performance and optimized javascript and css are very comparable to the YUI solution.

If you are specifically interested in a YUI Compressor option, check out http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com. This is a .net port of the YUI Compressor and also provides a MSBuild Task solution.

Lastly, I'll recommend my own OSS project, http://RequestReduce.com. This will crunch and combine your css and javascript at run time. It caches them and serves them using far future expires headers and customized ETags. Additionally, it can automatically sprite your background images. The nice thing about this is that it requires no codeor configuration for basic functionality. It can dynamically find your css and javascript files.

RequestReduce does use the ajax minifier but allows you to plug in your own minifier pretty easily. The wiki at https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce/wiki has sample code for accomplishing that.